# What is the best way to layout a seating chart and what is the best way to convert off a table structure?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I am trying to draw a seating chart onto a webpage dynamically (asp.net-mvc site) from data in a database and the first attempt, I was using a table as a way of laying out the `"grid"` of rows and columns and it looked something like this:

[image]

In my database I have a table called **Seat** table with the following **schema**:

**Id, Row, Column, Name**

To render the above, I would have this in my database:

```
| Id | Row | Col |   Name   |  
| 1  |  2  |  2  | Seat 1   |  
| 2  |  4  |  3  | Seat 2   |  
| 3  |  6  |  2  | Seat 3   |   
| 4  |  6  |  4  | Seat 123 |  
| 5  |  8  |  2  | Seat ABC |  
| 6  |  9  |  5  | Seat DEF |
```

So I am currently storing `"location"` as `"Row"` and `"Column"` in the database and then dynamically drawing the table above by just having a nested loop in my view.  The blue items are where seats are being rendered and the rest are spaces in between where there is nothing in the database for that `"cell"`.

Something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='space'></td>
        <td class='seat'><div class='seatInfo'>Seat ABC</div></td>
        <td class='space'></td>
    </tr>
```

Where the classes define some basic `CSS` around `backcolor` and `width` of cell.

The issue now is that the table structure forces alignment (which is good thing in some cases but ultimately a constraint as I now need to add seats that are larger than other ones and the table structure doesn't really allow that.

**For example, If I want seat in Row 6, Col 4 to be "taller" that automatically makes the seat in Row 6, Column 2 change in height (given that its a table) as well which I don't want.**

So here is an example floor plan in `Visio` and I am realizing that I don't see how I could build this view with this grid structure and maybe have to just go to complete absolute positioning for all seats and no longer have this `"row" / "col"` idea

[image]

I could have the ability to have a seat cover more than one row or column but that still only allows things to be `2x width` or `2x height` (versus having the flexibility to make something 1.5 times bigger than the "default" seat).

So I am thinking about changing the table to just a matrix of `divs / spans` and wanted to get some feedback before I started a big refactoring so I don't run into any blockers.

What would be the best way to lay out this set of information that would allow me to not get this too complication but also not hit this constraint so I can have more layout flexibility per seat.  I am happy to store more information in my database (like width or height) if required.

Comment: If you want rows with uniform height that contain cells which appear to be of different height, add an element inside each cell with the height you want and apply the shading to that element (not the `td`). If you want to achieve a best fit with arbitrary row heights, I'd consider [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: So i do actually have divs inside my TD (i was trying to make the question as simple as possible but i added a div in the question to make that more explicit) but i still have the issue where if one on row I have a list of seat right next to each other and in the row next I want to have spaces in between the seats.  It seems a table structure will always lead me to the issue where one row or col will affect the spacing of another

Comment: Well, if they don't affect the size of the entire row or column, you no longer have rows and columns, but a grid layout, and that doesn't sound right for seat arrangments ?

Comment: Yes, the table will impose constraints (which is both good and bad, as you note in the question). You can modify the divs to each have different heights/margins/whatever: http://jsfiddle.net/an31avpk/, which may or may not be flexible enough for your requirements.

Comment: @adeneo - maybe you are right and "Rows" and "Columns" and the idea of a grid is not the right model here

Comment: @Tim Medora - thanks for the example. I am doing something very similar now (right before i came to the conclusion that a table probably isn't correct here because while your example does allow different sizing for seats in the same row, it forces one one item to be in the vertical space and for the "short" one, the rest of the cell is space so i am not able to put another seat right below it.  I can only put a seat in the next "row" which might create too much vertical spacing between those two seats.

Comment: @Tim Medora - i started playing around with Masonry which is a pretty coll library but that seems to refit stuff as the screen size changes.  In my case i want more absolute positioning

Comment: Here's my protip of the day! Looking at the answers below, it seems to just get really complicated and difficult to read the seating charts when the table structure you had is lost. When the rows and columns of seats no longer line up, it looks strange, and it's hard to see what's really going on. I'd suggest something else completely. Showing that seats are larger with other visual cues, for instance color coding, or just adding text to the cells saying *"1.5x wide"* or something like that. It would look a lot cleaner, and ordinary people would still be able to read the seating chart.

Comment: ^ Feel free to transfer my bounty at any time ;) ........

Comment: since there are many good ideas already mentioned which dont seem to do the trick for you, would you mind showing a basic scheme of what a desired result could look like?

Comment: Do you want to play Battlefield `A1-J10` or do you want a radar `x: -50 + 50`, `y: -50 +50`?

You can add that data to your database and use it to feed classes, inline style, javascript indexes, grid systems, ... quite a lot of solutions. You said you've been working with Masonry? How about [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), which comes with a handy layout mode selection.

Comment: @TimVermaelen - i guess i was trying to see if i could have both (the preciseness of the absolute positioning and the sizing of every seat, with the benefits of still logically having some sort of matrix to be able to do operations on the matrix (like "Add Row" or "Add col" but i guess at some point i need to determine which is more important and make a tradeoff.

Comment: @Alex - I have added a visio floor layout image as an example of what flexibility i would like in sizing.  Ultimately i am building a tool for others to use so I have to decide If i just give them a full absolute flexibility with absolute positioning layout (versus having this idea of rows and columns so they can "Add Row' or "Add Columns" as they are building the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the most natural for you would be to use the same html structure that your database, ie

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.row2 {top: 40px;}
.row4 {top: 100px;}
.row6 {top: 160px; width: 80px;}
.row8 {top: 220px;}
.row9 {top: 250px;}
.col2 {left: 50px;}
.col3 {left: 150px;}
.col4 {left: 250px;}
.col5 {left: 350px;}
```

```html
<div class="row2 col2">1</div>
<div class="row4 col3">2</div>
<div class="row6 col2">3</div>
<div class="row6 col4">123</div>
<div class="row8 col2">abc</div>
<div class="row9 col5">def</div>
```

And then set all the display logic in the style, using absolute position.

There aren't so many CSS styles if you keep the display as a matrix; it would be only one style for every row and another one for every column.

If it is not a matrix, then you can ste specific styles, or may be better add some kind of class in the seats, and make the col position depending from both the column number and the row style.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I have got what exactly is the problem. Assuming, from your question and comments, that you need to fit in different seats with different heights without any space between 2 rows.

This is what I have done. I have created 6 columns and added the seats using a loop such that 1st element will go inside 1st column, 2nd element will go inside the 2nd column and so on. These newly added elements will have ids `row-1-col-1`, `row-1-col-2` ...

I have used mustache for templates for this demo

```
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="well">Book seats (1,5), (2,2), (2,4), (3,4) <br/>
           <button class="btn btn-primary">Book</button> </p>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script id="col_template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <div class = 'col-md-2 col-xs-2' > 
      <div class = "row seat" id = "col-{{num}}"> </div>
    </div>
</script>
<script id="row_col_template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    <div class = 'col-md-12 row{{rownum}}' id = "row-{{rownum}}-col-{{colnum}}">
    ({{rownum}} ,{{colnum}})                
    </div>
</script>
```

The final output generated will be

```
     Col1   |    Col2    |   Col3    |   Col4     // first template generates Col-n
  ========== ============ =========== ==========
  row1-col1 | row1-col2  | row1-col3 | row1-col4  // second template generates boxes inside Col-n
  row2-col1 | row2-col2  | row2-col3 | row2-col4
  row3-col1 | row3-col2  | row3-col3 | row3-col4
  row4-col1 | row4-col2  | row4-col3 | row4-col4
```

Now in the above example if the height of `row2-col3` is increased then `row3-col3` will be pushed down, rest elements won't besides won't be affected since others are placed in different containers(Col-n). I have added a `border-left` to know which row the seat is part of.

[image]

The issue with this method is that the final output doesn't look like a proper seat arrangement.

I am not including the JS here as its not required since most logic are done at the backend for you. Hope this is what you wanted.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/afd6757g/18/)

Comment: this is not really what i am looking for as it only partially solves the issue.  My requirement is less about "without any space between 2 rows" but rather to reflect an accurate picture where the seat layout is not a perfect "grid" and in some cases some seats take more space than others so the ratio lines up to what is really the layout on the floor.  In your example what if instead of the height that the width was bigger on one of the seats?

Comment: @leora Oh ok. Then as adeneo mentioned in his comment better to hav it same width and height and you can have the seat expand on hovering over the seat or you can have an info icon which on click would open a popover. [Something like this when on hover](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/afd6757g/19/)

Answer (score 1):

What if you defined a generic size unit for each seat like "seat size". For example, a standard seat size is worth "1". Your DB table would have an additional column for each seat's size. Any seats that are say twice as wide as a standard seat would have the value of "2" in the new DB column.

When rendering the HTML and CSS, each "seat" would be a `div` instead of a table cell, and would have hard-defined dimensions (even if was a % instead of px). e.g. a seat size of 1 may translate to 50px wide, so if a standard seat is 50px wide by 50px hight, a Seat worth 2 would be 100px wide by 50px high etc.

If you need to control size by height as well as width, then add another additional column to define the height and apply the same principle as above.

E.g.

**HTML**

```
<div class="seat-chart">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="seat" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"> Single Seat </div>
        <div class="seat" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"> Double Width Seat </div>
        <div class="seat" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"> Single Seat </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="seat" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"> Double Width Seat </div>
        <div class="seat" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"> Single Seat </div>
        <div class="seat" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"> Single Seat </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that you don't necessarily need to have hard defined sizes, you could use something like Bootstrap etc. or even css classes e.g. `seat-row-1`, `seat-row-2`, `seat-height-2` to make your layout responsive. But I think you may find controlling height and width easier with set dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are pretty good, but you might consider going for a more JS route. There are many packing algorithms where you can control the final layout but not have to constrain yourself to a single DOM structure that becomes very tightly coupled to the table layout.

For example, if you use [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) or something similar, you can just have a list of seats with their sizes set using styles and packery itself -- this way it's just a list of dom elements. You would have to check, of course, that you can rely on the placement, and in the case of Packery there's lots of options you wouldn't want, such as drag and dropping.

Comment: I don't think packery or masonry are the right solution to my problem as they seem good at layout and fitting things into boundries but in my case i am trying to replicate what is a very fixed and static layout

Answer (score 1):

The flexibility you're asking for is not possible without absolutely positioning your elements. You cannot dynamically place and size them and also maintain ultimate flexibility. This is why no one can give you a great answer.

A compromise would be to use a percentage based grid layout library and to set a maximum cell count per row in that library. Then you'd want to assign classes to each cell to define width and height (or style) based on respective size columns in your database for each record. I would consider doing this approach with Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

OR - you can bite the bullet and map groups of seats to seating templates with predefined absolute positions for each seat. Not fun, but pixel perfect.

Comment: By the way, my answers does involve absolute positioning. (I am not saying that it is great, of course :-). And it also allows for positioning every seat pixel by pixel, it depends only on how large do you want your style sheet

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the most efficient way to accomplish what you want is to use the display: flex css property. [Here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/) you can find out more about flex.

I created an simple example for you:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell" style="width: 120px;background: #0F0">1</div>
        <div class="cell">2</div>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">1</div>
        <div class="cell" style="height: 90px;background: #0FF">2</div>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">1</div>
        <div class="cell">2</div>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
    </div>
</div>

.row {
    display: flex;
}
.cell {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 90px;
    height: 60px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    border-right: 3px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

Hope this helped.

Fiddle: [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/3wbbL74j/)

Answer (score 0):

Latecomer to the party:  Why not just use the actual image, and html5 canvas to create seating chart?  Draw the jpg, overlay seating assignments directly over the seat in Canvas. (old skool, stubby pencil style).  Keep an array of seat location (SeatLocationName, xAxis, yAxis, personInSeat).  Keep it simple, really simple.  The key is to obtain an accurate image file of the floor plan.  When you plan for scaling, remember html5 canvas works at 96 pixels/inch.  xAxis and yAxis values must be scaled accordingly. (Choose your units wisely.. dots/pixels, or inches or mm.)

Remember too, that there are some very easy tools to go from large scale canvas --> PDF output.  Why PDF? Remember that free Adobe Reader tool now has the Poster option to printout large things on paper very easily...